# Why is my SQLCeCommand ExecuteReader failing?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

With the following code I get a less-than-helpful err msg (all I can see of the err msg in the truncated title bar of the exception dialog is, "System.Data.SQLServer...")

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM EVERYTHING";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query);
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(myConnStr); 
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
SqlCeDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); // <-- Blows up bigger than an Augustus Gloop pinata
```

### UPDATE

I added this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("query is {0}", query));
```

...to do a sanity check on just what the query that was failing was, to the end that clumps of hair are now scattered all about my work area. I had this to feed the query:

```
string vendorId = txtVendor.ToString().Trim();
```

...instead of this:

```
string vendorId = txtVendor.Text.ToString().Trim();
```

...and thus the query was "*SELECT BLA FROM BLA WHERE BLA = System.Windows.Forms.Label*"

Now I'm at least to a "No data exists for the row/column" err msg.

Comment: Doctor is in... I see a stress level very high. I suggest a break. In the meantime, please try to find the exception message

Comment: If you click "View Detail" when the exception pops up you should get more information.

Comment: There is no "View Detail" with this err msg. It's a custom exception dialog that, in this case, is not a big help.

Comment: It gets very stressful when you have to stress to people that you're not overstressed.

Comment: Please post the whole query and the complete error message. How can we help you if you're not adding enough information?

Comment: Ok add a try/catch block around that code and in the catch display the exception.message

Comment: I changed the query to a plain vanilla one (kind of like the fake one above) and it runs, so it's the dang query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if CF supports the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` option.

Can you write it this way?

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM EVERYTHING";
var table = new DataTable();
using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, new SqlCeConnection(myConnStr)); {
  try {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
  } catch (SqlException err) {
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message); // <= Put a Break Point here.
  } finally {
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  } 
}
object col1 = null;
string strCol2 = null;
if (0 < table.Rows.Count) {
  col1 = table.Rows[0][0];
  object obj = table.Rows[0][1];
  if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value)) {
    strCol2 = obj.ToString();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added **DataTable** and read 2 items from `Row[0]`.

Comment: I can't put a break point - all I can do is MessageBox.Show()s. But I'll try to adapt this.

Comment: I only need/want one row returned, but I'm under the impression that ExecuteScalar only returns 1 val, and I need the vals from two columns. I'm right, right (that ExecuteScalar won't be valid for this scenario)?

Comment: Because I'm getting, "Exception: No data exists for the row/column.", I was hoping to use your "peek" code like so:

if (-1 < myReader.Peek()) { <assign vals> }

...but Peek is not a member of SqlCeDataReader (at least not in the version I'm using (.NET 1.1)).

Comment: Very sorry, Clay. I got busy on other stuff. I've updated the answer with how to read the data in.